# Why is the adjoint of a matrix in numpy obtained by np.matrix.getH()

Tags: python, numpy

when I want to get the adjoint of a numpy array, I have to type

```
A = np.matrix([...])
A.getH()
```

I am curious about the naming. Why is it

```
np.matrix.getH()?
```

In contrast, transpose and conjugate are implemented as

```
ndarray.transpose()
ndarray.conjugate()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the complex conjugate or the **Hermitian transpose** of a matrix with complex entries *A** obtained from *A* gives the adjoint matrix.

Long story short, **getH** smells like *get Hermitian transpose*.

Comment: You could also add a note to your answer that the attribute `.H` returns the same result as `.getH()`, similar to how `.T` gives the transpose.

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as you use `np.conj(A).T`.